# Why is my kitchen light frame showing it is live

Tags: electrical

I have an electrical safety tester to check what is "current" live, like power points and wiring before you touch it. An electrician came to install a new batten light on my kitchen ceiling. Everything works fine but when I place my probe near the light frame it indicates that the frame is live all around. I know it isn't because I saw the sparky touch it during final assembly, so why is my probe indicating a live situation on the fully assembled outside frame?

Comment: it is actually sparking ? Non contact testers are not reliable, use multimeter

Comment: multimeters are not reliable either.

Comment: What happens if you touch other things with metal enclosures, for instance your consumer unit if it's metal?  Does your house have its own ground spike?

Comment: @Jasen what is ?

Comment: I can think of nothing that's both safe and affordable.

Comment: @Jasen interesting, but you know multimeter are not reliable

Comment: yeah, for example they'll show phantom voltage.

Comment: @Jasen easy fix, if they do, reduce the voltage setting on the scale, which will reduce the resistor, thus draw more current, and the ghost might vanish

Comment: None of my CATIII meters have a range knob (all auto-range)  and meters that aren't CATIII should not be used on energised house wiring.

Comment: Does it show hot only when the power is on, or when it's off, too?

Answer (score 1):

The tester works by Capacitive Coupling. Which I believe is a fancy way to say detects electric waves. Your tester is just picking up this coupling probably because the hot wire in the fixture is against the frame.  I have encountered this myself. It does not mean the frame is hot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the frame is not grounded. Possibly it should be grounded, but I would not expect an electrician to miss that.

Most likely the detector is just picking up the high frequency waves from the ballast.